Official source for OS version 14.0 for creating bootable drive
I am trying to create bootable drives for various versions of Mac OS. In particular, I would like to create an installer for the original version of Sonoma (14.0). However, I do not see this version listed at this site: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102662
I also don't see it available in the downloads on the developer page.
Is there an official source for acquiring 14.0?
PS: I found How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?, and this is useful and contains some older versions of Sonoma, but not 14.0.
I strongly feel that at some point in history, there was a page or API you could access through the developer site that allowed downloading any OS version. I remember visiting this site 2 to 3 years ago, but I can't find it anymore.

If this is about old versions in general, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos. If it is about 14. 0, please edit the question and it’s title to focus on this.

@nohillside . Thanks for the link. The accepted answer has the problems I described in my question (incomplete). In particular, there is not a version of Sonoma as far as I can tell. Some of the other answers mention softwareupdate which I found earlier and is useful, but it is still incomplete and does not include 14.0. Editing the question.

Mist (which is one of the solutions proposed in the accepted answer) lists all versions available. In your case, 14.2.1 is the oldest which still can be installed.

@nohillside I checked the Mist source code and the catalog that it uses, and the oldest version seems to be the same as the command line tool I used above, which is 14.2.1 not 14.0. They are probably checking the same place. So I still need a solution for 14.0.

There are no Apple links to the installer for 14.0. Perhaps ask if anyone has kept their installer for 14.0 and a) would be willing to let you have it, and b) you trust not to have altered it.

@nohillside I figured it out that I would only need to go back to 14.3.1 to resolve my issue, so I don't really need this anymore if you all want to close it again.
